# Responsive Iframes height with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I am using Bootstrap and trying to stack several iframes in rows of 3. 
The problem is that the iframes push down the ones below like they had bottom margin or something similar. I'm using this code:

```
<div class="container">

     <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                    <div class="proj-container">
                            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                               <iframe class="embed-responsive-item"src=''></iframe>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                     <div class="proj-container">
                            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                               <iframe class="embed-responsive-item"src=''></iframe>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                     <div class="proj-container">
                            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                               <iframe class="embed-responsive-item"src=''></iframe>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                     <div class="proj-container">
                            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                               <iframe class="embed-responsive-item"src=''></iframe>
                            </div>
                    </div>



                </div>
            </div>

</div>
```

I left the sources empty in this example, but my opinion is that the iframe actually stretch invisibly for the height of the whole content of the page they refer to.

Any idea on how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Is hard to say without a code sample. But maybe it helps if you put the iframes into separate divs and not directly into the col-md-4 col-xs-12 ?

Comment: @ Johann Kratzik That actually helped a lot, might work as solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome! I am glad that I could help